# Failed to update SwiftUI preview when using .OnReceive Method

Tags: ios, swift, canvas, swiftui, combine

I have implemented the .OnReceive method in a SwiftUI view to be able to keep track of some variebles.

[image: onCreate]

[image: states]

But as you can see I have all the .onReceive's code is commented and the reason is that if I don't I get the following error on the canvas:

[image: canvas error]

This is my ContentView_Previews Struct:
[image]

Could anyone help me to understand the error? I suspect that the ContentView_Previews Struct need some extra value to be able to interpret the view on the canvas.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It cannot be tested by screenshot. Would you provide demo code?

Comment: Please don't create questions with screenshots of your code. Post the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that the preview cannot render, and the reason for that is that it doesn't have the `@EnvironmentObject var appState: States` that your `LoginView` uses in the `.onReceive`.

So, you need to set it:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      LoginView()
         .previewLayout(.device)
         .environmentObject(States())  // here
   }
}
```